# Python (on replit.com) only allowing one instance of one function to run at a time

Tags: python, string, csv, file, replit

Here is some code I'm working on requiring string and the opening and closing of files.

```
#Importing required Packages---------------------------------------------
import string

# Importing Datasets-----------------------------------------------------
allNames = open("allNames.csv", "r")
onlyNames = open("onlyNames.csv", "r")

#=========Tasks==========================================================
# [1] findName(name, outputFile)-----------------------------------------

# Works ####
def findName(name, outputFile):
  outfile = open(outputFile + ".csv", "w")  # Output file
  outfile.write("Artist \tSong \tYear\n") # Initial title lines
  alreadyAdded = [] # List of lines already added to remove duplicates
  for aline in allNames: # Looping through allNames.csv
    fields = aline.split("\t") # Splitting elements of a line into a list
    if fields[-1] == name + "\n": # Selecting lines with only the specified name (last element)
      dataline = fields[0] + "\t" + fields[1] + "\t" + fields[3] # Each line in the .csv file
      if dataline not in alreadyAdded: # Removing Duplicates
        outfile.write(dataline + "\n") # Writing the file
        alreadyAdded.append(dataline) # Adding lines already added
  outfile.close()

# findName("Mary Anne", "mary anne")
# findName("Jack", "jack")
# findName("Mary", "mary")
# findName("Peter", "peter")
```

The code serves its intended purpose as I get an exported file. However, this only works for one function at a time, for example if I try to run both `findName("Mary Anne", "mary anne")` and `findName("Jack", "jack")` at the same time, the second instance of the function does not work. Moreover, all subsequent functions on the project file do not work unless I comment out this code.

Let me know what the issue is, thank you!

Comment: [OP here] I assumed this had something to do with the positioning of `outfile.close()` but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: After you have read all of the lines in `allNames`, there are no more lines to be read.  You'd need to use `allNames.seek(0)` to rewind to the beginning of the file.

Comment: @jasonharper, this worked, thank you so much. (I put it right before `outfile.close()`)